# how to skip this loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I have got this code:

`for i in *.txt; do cp $i ./${i%%.*}.text; done`

but the problem I have is, that I want to have the exact same command without using the loop.
can anybody help me with this?
ive tried anything possible to solve this problem but I couldnt find a solution.

thanks

Comment: _ive tried anything possible to solve this problem_ Post what you have tried, at least one approach of the whole possible ways

Comment: Im quite new to shell-skripting. So first I tried using pipes so that the command after cp might change all files that have the ending *.txt. But i guess that this isnt possible due to wrong syntax. For example I tried      
`ls *.txt | cp *.txt ./$(*.txt%%.*}.text` 
but as you can imagine this seems to be completely wrong hehe

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop? :)

Comment: just want to figure out if it is possible. i just prefer the way of not using a loop

Comment: What are you trying to *accomplish*? Are you just trying to rename all the .txt files to .text? Because that isn't what that's going to do anyway.

Comment: `man rename`...

Comment: `rename` maybe a good option, but not available on my system. `for f in ?.txt; do cp $f ${f%.txt}.text; done` seems the simplest solution. We could hack out something using `find`, but it hardly seems worth the effort unless there are scores of thousands of files, in which case I'd personally still just write a quick script in Perl.

Comment: `rename` is not up to the task. OP used `cp`, not `mv`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` you can use

```
printf '%s\0' *.txt | sed -z 's/\.txt$//' | xargs -0 -n1 -I_ cp _.txt _.text
```

This is safe even if the file names contain linebreaks.

`xargs` seems to be faster than the `for` loop. I tested as follows:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ touch {0..9999}.{txt,text}
$ time printf ... xargs ...
6.6 s
$ time for ... do ...
13.5 s
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with xargs, something similar to:

```
ls *.txt | xargs -n 1 -I{} cp {} ./${{}%%.*}.text
```

Comment: Not quite sure about this one `${{}%%.*}` :)

Comment: Why not? The {} gets substituted by the name read by xargs from ls. Then, the %%.* part gets rid of the last dot and following chars.

Comment: Another option would be using basename:

    ls *.txt | xargs -n 1 -I{} cp {} $(basename {} .txt).text

And if your files contains spaces then you should take care of them and use a zero-ended version, as suggested in the other comment:

    printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -0 -n 1 -I{} cp {} $(basename {} .txt).text

Comment: Because with `${{}%%.*}` you will get bad substitution.

Comment: Bash will try to expand `${{}%%.*}` *before* `xargs` is executed. But `{}` is not a variable, so you will get a *bad substitution* error. Even if you quoted that part, it would not work. In bash `${var%%.*}` removes the extension from the string *stored inside* the variable `var`. In your case there is no variable, you would have to use something like `var={} cp {} ${var%%.*}.text`, but even then it wouldn't work, because `xargs` executes `cp` directly without using bash. `${...}` simply won't be expanded by `xargs`.

Comment: Touchê! You are right @Socowi! Thanks for the explanation.
In that case, the option with basename should work.